# Where's my entities i select in ADO.net data model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, edmx

I 'm learning entity framework for the first time and i use visual studio 2012.

So I'm little confused .

---

instead just `.edmx` file with its designer.cs i found four files and i never found my tables and views which i select in the previous step through the wizard of ADO.net Entity Data Model in my designer  ?

Could some one Explain in details what those files are ? is the Entity Framework 5 so advanced on the Entity Framework 4.1?

Should i return to use V.S 2008 instead if i want to learn Entity Framework easily ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.EDMX is an XML file used to store the mapping metadata between your database and your objects (entities). Here is a good introduction session on developing EF solutions using "Model First" approach :

[Introduction to Model First development using Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj205424)

There are bunch of new features added in Entity Framework 5.0 but the core is still the same. I would also recommend you to checkout the [Entity Framework Code First approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542).

Answer (score 1):

Your .edmx file is a Entity Container, just create new object and use your data.

Container name you can find in .edmx properties.